# sum by year and insert missing entries with 0

Tags: bash, awk

I have a report for year-month entries like below

```
201703 5
201708 10
201709 20
201710 40
201711 80
201712 100
201802 0
201803 25
201804 50
201805 50
201806 150
201807 300
201808 200
201902 10
```

I need to sum the year-month entries by year and print after all the months for that particular year. The year-month can have missing entries for any month(s).
For those months the a dummy value (0) should be inserted.

Required output:

```
201703 5
201704 0
201705 0
201706 0
201707 0
201708 10
201709 20
201710 40
201711 80
201712 100
2017 255
201801 0
201802 0
201803 25
201804 50
201805 50
201806 150
201807 300
201808 200
201809 0
201810 0
201811 0
201812 0
2018 775
201901 0
201902 10
201903 0
2019 10
```

I can get the summary of year by using below command.

```
awk ' { c=substr($1,0,4); if(c!=p) { print p,s ;s=0} s=s+$2 ; p=c ; print } ' ym.dat
```

But, how to insert entries for the missing ones?.
Also the last entry should not exceed current (system time) year-month. i.e for this specific example, dummy values should not be inserted for 201904..201905.. etc. It should just stop with 201903

Comment: Do you want the first ones to be added too? I.e. 201701 etc

Comment: no.. it says something start of the report.. so adding 201701 is incorrect

Comment: How do you recognise a "missing entry" for 201701 from a report starting at 201702?

Comment: Why is there a `0` entry for `201903` but not for other months of `2019`?

Comment: it should be between the start of the report and the end of current year-month

Comment: @anubhava 201903 is current ( system) year-month.. so it should be included..

Comment: Does the data have to be validated, or can it simply be assumed valid.  If a line 201822 appears, what should happen, or is it simply deemed 'impossible'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.. no that wouldn't happen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` script `mmyy.awk`:

```
{
   rec[$1] = $2;
   yy=substr($1, 1, 4)
   mm=substr($1, 5, 2) + 0
   ys[yy] += $2
}

NR == 1 {
   fm = mm
   fy = yy
}

END {
   for (y=fy; y<=cy; y++)
      for (m=1; m<=12; m++) {
         # print previous years sums
         if (m == 1 && y-1 in ys)
            print y-1, ys[y-1]

         if (y == fy && m < fm)
            continue;
         else if (y == cy && m > cm)
            break;

         # print year month with values or 0 if entry is missing
         k = sprintf("%d%02d", y, m)
         printf "%d%02d %d\n", y, m, (k in rec ? rec[k] : 0)
      }
      print y-1, ys[y-1]
}
```

Then call it as:

```
awk -v cy=$(date '+%Y') -v cm=$(date '+%m') -f mmyy.awk file
```

```
201703 5
201704 0
201705 0
201706 0
201707 0
201708 10
201709 20
201710 40
201711 80
201712 100
2017 255
201801 0
201802 0
201803 25
201804 50
201805 50
201806 150
201807 300
201808 200
201809 0
201810 0
201811 0
201812 0
2018 775
201901 0
201902 10
201903 0
2019 10
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for strftime():

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    begDate = $1
    endDate = strftime("%Y%m")
}
{
    val[$1] = $NF
    year = substr($1,1,4)
}
year != prevYear { prt(); prevYear=year }
END { prt() }

function prt(   mth, sum, date) {
    if (prevYear != "") {
        for (mth=1; mth<=12; mth++) {
            date = sprintf("%04d%02d", prevYear, mth)
            if ( (date >= begDate) && (date <=endDate) ) {
                print date, val[date]+0
                sum += val[date]
                delete val[date]
            }
        }
        print prevYear, sum+0
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f  tst.awk file
201703 5
201704 0
201705 0
201706 0
201707 0
201708 10
201709 20
201710 40
201711 80
201712 100
2017 255
201801 0
201802 0
201803 25
201804 50
201805 50
201806 150
201807 300
201808 200
201809 0
201810 0
201811 0
201812 0
2018 775
201901 0
201902 10
201903 0
2019 10
```

With other awks you'd just pass in endDate using `awk -v endDate=$(date +'%Y%m') '...'`

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane '$start ||= $F[0];
            $Y{substr $F[0], 0, 4} += $F[1];
            $YM{$F[0]} = $F[1];
            END { for $y (sort keys %Y) {
                      for $m (1 .. 12) {
                          $m = sprintf "%02d", $m;
                          next if "$y$m" lt $start;
                          print "$y$m ", $YM{$y . $m} || 0;
                          last if $y == 1900 + (localtime)[5]
                               && (localtime)[4] < $m;
                      }
                      print "$y ", $Y{$y} || 0;
                  }
              }' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) extracts the year from the YYYYMM date. Hashes %Y and %YM use dates and keys and the counts as values. That's why the year hash uses `+=` which adds the value to the already accumulated one.
- The END block is evaluated after the input has been exhausted.
- It just iterates over the years stored in the hash, the range 1 .. 12 is used for month to insert the zeroes (the `||` operator prints it).
- [next](http://p3rl.org/next) and `$start` skips the months before the start of the report.
- [last](http://p3rl.org/last) is responsible for skipping the rest of the current year.

Comment: can you fix the start of the YM

Answer (score 1):

The following awk script will do what you expect. The idea is:

- store data in an array
- print and sum only when the year changes

This gives:

```
# function that prints the year starting
# at month m1 and ending at m2
function print_year(m1,m2,   s,str) {
    s=0
    for(i=(m1+0); i<=(m2+0); ++i) { 
       str=y sprintf("%0.2d",i);
       print str, a[str]+0; s+=a[str]
    }
    print y,s
}

# This works for GNU awk, replace for posix with a call as
# awk -v stime=$(date "+%Y%m") -f script.awk file
BEGIN{ stime=strftime("%Y%m") }
# initializer on first record    
(NR==1){ y=substr($1,1,4); m1=substr($1,5) }
# print intermediate year
(substr($1,1,4) != y) { 
    print_year(m1,12)
    y=substr($1,1,4); m1="01";
    delete a
}
# set array value and keep track of last month
{a[$1]=$2; m2=substr($1,5)}
# check if entry is still valid (past stime or not)
($1 > stime) { exit }
# print all missing years full
# print last year upto system time month
END { 
  for (;y<substr(stime,1,4)+0;y++) { print_year(m1,12); m1=1; m2=12; }
  print_year(m1,substr(stime,5))
}
```

Comment: 201903 entry is missing in the output

Comment: @stack0114106 there is no 201903 in your input, so it cannot be in your output. Last month is february.

Comment: I mentioned it as current (i,e system) year-month.. added the clarification in the question also

Comment: np.. where have you used the system time?.. when I run with the same input in next month, i,e April.. it should have one entry for 201904 as well..

Comment: @stack0114106 Should work now but I do not know if it will cover all special cases, such as no entries before systime, empty file, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, btw. Friday afternoon brain frier. Time to head home.

In awk. The optional endtime and its value are brought in as arguments:

```
$ awk -v arg1=201904 -v arg2=100 '          # optional parameters
function foo(ym,v) {
    while(p<ym){
        y=substr(p,1,4)                     # get year from previous round
        m=substr(p,5,2)+0                   # get month
        p=y+(m==12) sprintf("%02d",m%12+1)  # December magic
        if(m==12)
            print y,s[y]                    # print the sums (delete maybe?)
        print p, (p==ym?v:0)                # print yyyymm and 0/$2
    }
}
{
    s[substr($1,1,4)]+=$2                   # sums in array, year index
}
NR==1 {                                     # handle first record
    print
    p=$1
}
NR>1 {
    foo($1,$2)
}
END {
    if(arg1)
        foo(arg1,arg2)
    print y=substr($1,1,4),s[y]+arg2
}' file
```

Tail from output:

```
2018 775
201901 0
201902 10
201903 0
201904 100
2019 110
```

Comment: hi James.. thanks for the answer.. the current (system) month entry 201903 is missing..

Comment: @stack0114106 Completely missed that. I guess I'm not heading home, yet.

Comment: The current month entry, if desired, is as an argument.

Comment: I would not need it as art.. then folks running it would not change for upcoming months.. np I can edit iy

Comment: I'll copy the logic from @EdMorton's answer once I get home. ;D I mean I buy it with an upvote...

Comment: :-).. happy weekend James